# stable_sort not keeping order of elements

Tags: c++

i have an std::vector of Object, Object can be Empty or NotEmpty (which is an internal status, the Object itself is always valid).

I want to sort the vector by internal status, while keep the relative order it has before the sorting.

in theory (unless im missing something) i only need to check for the internal status of the first element for the comparing function:

```
    // i want to keep the NonEmptys first
    std::stable_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto& first, const auto& second)
    {
        return first.getStatus() != Status::Empty;
    });
```

thing is this does not keep the same order as it was before the sorting, in fact, if i sort again it will just reverse the order of the NonEmptys.

I read about strict weak ordering, and tried several comparing functions always with the same result (even tried if both Empty return false).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you're sorting an array, you have to compare the two elements to determine which should go first.

Comment: @sap  It is not clear what is the order of the sorted elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparator you pass into `std::stable_sort` does not form a valid ordering. For example, if we have `object1` and `object2` as both empty, then `object1 < object2` *and* `object2 < object1` (using your comparator). This does not play well with the standard sort functions.

What you really want is [`std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition):

```
std::stable_partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto& object)
{
    return object.getStatus() != Status::Empty;
});
```

Comment: just read the documentation for partition() you're exactly right, that's what i wanted since it doesn't compare, it just uses true or false for deciding what comes first. thanks so much ill accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow allows me (in 6min).

Answer (score 3):

From [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort#Parameters)

> **Parameters**
>
> **comp**   -   comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

This means, in order to sort the non-empty first, the comparison function must return true, if `first` is non-empty and `second` is empty. The other way round, it must return false. It must also return false, if both are empty or both are non-empty, because then `first` is not less than `second`.

So the comparison function reduces to

```
[](const auto &first, const auto &second) {
    return first.getStatus() != Status::Empty && second.getStatus() == Status.Empty;
}
```

Now, `std::stable_sort` knows which element is *less*, and equally important, which elements are *equivalent*.

Comment: Not equal, *equivalent*. I.e. not ordered in relation to each other.

Comment: @StoryTeller Not sure, although according to https://english.stackexchange.com/a/317792/72037 you might be right. On the other side, I'm not an english native speaker.

Comment: It's just the terminology employed by the standard for these predicates. For instance, [unordered maps](http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#6) mention "equivalent keys".